# ggplot: shift position of y and x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to change the position of the y-axis and x-axis to zero, eventhough I have negative values. I read in a Google group that it was not possible with `ggplot` back then. Has this feature been implemented since?

For example, when I have this data

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(
  S = rep(c(10, 5, 3.3, 2.5, 1.66, 0.62), 2),
  v = c(c(0.202, 0.079, 0.0597, 0.0565, 0.0365, 0.0318), 
        c(0.25, 0.14, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04, 0.03)),
  inhibitor = rep(c("nein", "ja"), each = 6)
)
```

I'd like to change the axis position according to the `hline` and `vline` I added manually.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(y = v, x = S, shape = inhibitor)) + 
  geom_point() +
  xlim(c(-2, 10)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = inhibitor), 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, 
              fullrange = TRUE, color = "black") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need `+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 0.25))` ? This zooms into your plot. See https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf Second page, bottom right.

Comment: No, I want the `hline` and `vline` to be the lines for the axes (with axis ticks and everything).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about removing the space between the axis and the axis-labels?

The `expand` argument in the scale function for ggplot2 sets the padding between plot limit and the axes.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(y = v, x = S, shape = inhibitor)) + 
    geom_point() +
    xlim(c(-2, 10)) + 
    geom_smooth(aes(linetype = inhibitor), 
                method = "lm", se = FALSE, 
                fullrange = TRUE, color = "black") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: No, I need the negative space, too. I want the exact same frame as in my example but with the y axis at the position of the `geom_vline()` and the x axis at the position of the `geom_hline()`.

Answer (score 0):

#try this code. I found it upon search:

```
    shift_axis <- function(p, y=0){
  g <- ggplotGrob(p)
  dummy <- data.frame(y=y)
  ax <- g[["grobs"]][g$layout$name == "axis-b"][[1]]
  p + annotation_custom(grid::grobTree(ax, vp = grid::viewport(y=1, height=sum(ax$height))), 
                        ymax=y, ymin=y) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=y), data = dummy) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
  
}
```

#p is your ggplot code, run it, then run:

```
shift_axis(p, 0)
```